# Dynamic ngModel and ngBind with a custom directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I want to create a directive that creates a auto generated ngModel for each input field, and below each input field a  that has ng-bind to the ngModel of the element above so here's the directive that i did so far

```
  app.directive('cmsInput', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        compile: function(element, attrs)
        {
            var type = attrs.type || 'text';
            var required = attrs.hasOwnProperty('required') ? "required='required'" : "";
            var htmlText = '<div class="form-group"  ng-controller="DashboardController">' +
                '<label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="' + attrs.formId + '">' + attrs.label + '</label>' +
                    '<div class="col-sm-10">' +
                    '<input ng-model="content.'+attrs.formId +'" type="' + type + '" class="form-control" id="' + attrs.formId + '" name="' + attrs.formId + '" ' + required + '>' +
                    '<span ng-bind="content.'+attrs.formId+'"></span></div>' +
                '</div>';
            element.replaceWith(htmlText);
        }
    }
})
```

so this direcive gives me the input elements but the ngBind doesn't work .

here's is the html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Test Title</title>
</head>


<body>
<cms-input label="Email address" form-id="emailAddress" type="email" required /></cms-input>

<cms-input label="Name" form-id="name" type="text"/></cms-input>

<cms-input label="Header" form-id="header" type="text"/></cms-input>

<cms-input label="Password" form-id="password" type="password"/></cms-input>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Are you sure that the ng-model works fine?

Comment: Not sure really, how can i test it in this case ?

Comment: Maybe you could add a button which calls a function in your controller which logs or alerts the variable.
As parameter you could give `attrs.formId` which then looks (in an Array or something - Ok, I see you have Objects, should work with `$scope.content[id]`, when `id` is your `attrs.formId` sent from the Button). Then you can check if the value really is correct

Comment: okay i'll give it a try

Comment: No, even the model it doesn't work it is undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a couple things here, but the only one that really is causing problems is not having $scope.content initialized to an object. You can see a working example here: http://jsbin.com/bocuzi/1/edit?html,js,output

One other thing that might have thrown you off is if you were testing this all out by using the email field and not putting in a valid email address. Because of the way ngModelController works, it won't actually set the $scope value unless it passes validation. None of the other fields will have that limitation since they're using the text or password types.

Hope that helps.

Comment: it is actually initialised in the controller as         $scope.content = {}; and i tested it not only with the email, it doesn't work for all the input fields

Comment: Did you check my working example and look for any other differences?

Comment: yes, it is pretty much the same, i can't see any differences but still it doesn't work...

Comment: I also noticed that you have made the directive elements in the HTML self-closing but you also included closing tags. I don't think that'll make a difference, but it's worth a shot.

Comment: this is not the problem i think.but i have one thing that may cause the error and i forgot to mention is that the html code is included to the page  by data-ng-include

Comment: The email only works if its valid. Try to really look carefully, sometimes a small thing is the cause.... ;) good luck

Comment: i'm not testing by the email, i tried others but they don't, i'm still searching for the problem

Comment: @ziz194 The ngInclude is the issue. It creates a child scope. You're going to need to do something like $parent.content

Comment: i added $parent.content and it still doesn't work, do you have any idea how to access the ngInclude scope ?

Comment: The other thing you can do is have the directive make sure to initialize the $scope.content object if it doesn't exist, and it'll just create it for you. The problem there would be that it will be on that new scope and I'm not sure if you need it on the parent scope without seeing it all in context.

Comment: how to do that initialising the scope in the directive ?

Comment: I updated the example with the initialization: http://jsbin.com/bocuzi/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: still doesn't work, it is really frustrating, since it works for you with the same code

Comment: The ng-bind on the span still isn't working? Or something further down the chain that relies on the $scope.content? If the ng-bind still isn't working with the directive controller initiation, there are other outside factors and I'm not sure I can help anymore without seeing more context. If it's something later on that relies on the $scope.content, we can address that too but I'll need more information.

Comment: Now i'm sure that it is a problem of the ngInclude because i copied and pasted the code to the html page without using ngInclude and it works...but i should find a way to do it with ngInclude